# panResponder - how often is onPanResponderMove called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, drag-and-drop

I'm using [React Native PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html), and on `onPanResponderMove` I want to re render a view with new position (creating a dragndrop feel).

I see the callback being called a lot of times but I can not find how many times per second this callback is actually called.

With a user panning a lot to left and right, how many times per second (max) is this callback called?